# Vuetify fast fail is not preventing the form from being sent

Tags: forms, vue.js, error-handling, vuetify.js, fast-fail

Vuetify fast fail checks and displays the error message, but the form is sent anyway.

```
<script setup>

  import { ref } from "vue"
  
  const firstName = ref('')
  const firstNameRules = [
    value => {
      if (value?.length > 3) return true
      return 'First name must be at least 3 characters.'
    }
  ]
   
  function submit() {
    alert(`${firstName}`)  
  }
 
</script>

<template>
  <v-form fast-fail @submit.prevent="submit">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="firstName"
        label="First name"
        :rules="firstNameRules"
      ></v-text-field>
      </v-form>
</template>
```

The function submit always runs, even with the error being shown. How to make the error checking prevent the form from being submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`:fast-fail`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#props-fast-fail) prop stops validation when a check fails (in contrast to the default behavior, which always validates all inputs). It has nothing to do with submitting or submit events.

Instead, the [`@submit`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-form/#events-submit) handler receives a [SubmitEventPromise](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/composables/form.ts#L48-L48), which is a regular submit event merged with a promise. You can await that promise for the validation result and abort the submit if validation failed:

```
async function submit(submitEventPromise) {
  const { valid, errors } = await submitEventPromise
  if (!valid) {
    return // abort submit
  }
  ... // perform submit
}
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)